# How to fix "XML Parsing Error: syntax error" in React JS?

Tags: reactjs, mern

I am trying to setup user login/auth in MERN stack. When I fill the register form and submit I get the following message on console.

```
XML Parsing Error: syntax error
Location: http://localhost:3000/api/users/register
Line Number 1, Column 1:
```

I have tested my api using Postman and everything seems to be working fine.
Below is my api for register requuest:

```
// API routes
// @routes POST api/users/register
// @access Public

// @route POST api/users/register
// @desc Register user
// @access Public
router.post("/register", (req, res) => {
  // Form validation

  const { errors, isValid } = validateRegisterInput(req.body);

  // Check validation
  if (!isValid) {
    return res.status(400).json(errors);
  }

  User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }).then(user => {
    if (user) {
      return res.status(400).json({ email: "Email already exists" });
    } else {
      const newUser = new User({
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password
      });

      // Hash password before saving in database
      bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
        bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          newUser.password = hash;
          newUser
            .save()
            .then(user => res.json(user))
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
        });
      });
    }
  });
});
```

On the client side: 
Register.jsx

```
import ...

class Register extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: "",
      email: "",
      password: "",
      password2: "",
      errors: {}
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // If logged in and user navigates to Register page, should redirect them to dashboard
    if (this.props.auth.isAuthenticated) {
      this.props.history.push("/dashboard");
    }
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.errors) {
      this.setState({
        errors: nextProps.errors
      });
    }
  }

  onChange = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.id]: e.target.value });
  };

  onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const newUser = {
      name: this.state.name,
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password,
      password2: this.state.password2
    };

    this.props.registerUser(newUser, this.props.history);
  };

  render() {
    const { errors } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col s8 offset-s2">
            <Link to="/" className="btn-flat waves-effect">
              <i className="material-icons left">keyboard_backspace</i> Back to
              home
            </Link>
            <div className="col s12" style={{ paddingLeft: "11.250px" }}>
              <h4>
                <b>Register</b> below
              </h4>
              <p className="grey-text text-darken-1">
                Already have an account? <Link to="/login">Log in</Link>
              </p>
            </div>
            <form noValidate onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
              <div className="input-field col s12">
                <input
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                  value={this.state.name}
                  error={errors.name}
                  id="name"
                  type="text"
                  className={classnames("", {
                    invalid: errors.name
                  })}
                />
                <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
                <span className="red-text">{errors.name}</span>
              </div>
              <div className="input-field col s12">
                <input
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                  value={this.state.email}
                  error={errors.email}
                  id="email"
                  type="email"
                  className={classnames("", {
                    invalid: errors.email
                  })}
                />
                <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                <span className="red-text">{errors.email}</span>
              </div>
              <div className="input-field col s12">
                <input
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                  value={this.state.password}
                  error={errors.password}
                  id="password"
                  type="password"
                  className={classnames("", {
                    invalid: errors.password
                  })}
                />
                <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                <span className="red-text">{errors.password}</span>
              </div>
              <div className="input-field col s12">
                <input
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                  value={this.state.password2}
                  error={errors.password2}
                  id="password2"
                  type="password"
                  className={classnames("", {
                    invalid: errors.password2
                  })}
                />
                <label htmlFor="password2">Confirm Password</label>
                <span className="red-text">{errors.password2}</span>
              </div>
              <div className="col s12" style={{ paddingLeft: "11.250px" }}>
                <button
                  style={{
                    width: "150px",
                    borderRadius: "3px",
                    letterSpacing: "1.5px",
                    marginTop: "1rem"
                  }}
                  type="submit"
                  className="btn btn-large waves-effect waves-light hoverable blue accent-3"
                >
                  Sign up
                </button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Register.propTypes = {
  registerUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  errors: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth,
  errors: state.errors
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { registerUser }
)(withRouter(Register));
```

I cannot see what is wrong in the code. I have followed a tutorial and done the exact same thing.
My registerUser method is in the following file. 
authActions.js

```
// Register User
export const registerUser = (userData, history) => dispatch => {
  axios
    .post("/api/users/register", userData)
    .then(res => history.push("/login")) // re-direct to login on successful register
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ERRORS,
        payload: err.response.data
      })
    );
};

// Login - get user token
export const loginUser = userData => dispatch => {
  axios
    .post("/api/users/login", userData)
    .then(res => {
      // Save to localStorage

// Set token to localStorage
      const { token } = res.data;
      localStorage.setItem("jwtToken", token);
      // Set token to Auth header
      setAuthToken(token);
      // Decode token to get user data
      const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
      // Set current user
      dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded));
    })
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ERRORS,
        payload: err.response.data
      })
    );
};

// Set logged in user
export const setCurrentUser = decoded => {
  return {
    type: SET_CURRENT_USER,
    payload: decoded
  };
};

// User loading
export const setUserLoading = () => {
  return {
    type: USER_LOADING
  };
};

// Log user out
export const logoutUser = () => dispatch => {
  // Remove token from local storage
  localStorage.removeItem("jwtToken");
  // Remove auth header for future requests
  setAuthToken(false);
  // Set current user to empty object {} which will set isAuthenticated to false
  dispatch(setCurrentUser({}));
};
```

Comment: Please post the `registerUser` method as well since it is most likely what's throwing the error.

Comment: Made some updates..